# Saying Amen to the bracha before Shema outside of zman

Tags: halacha, zemanim, amen

The reason some do not saying amen to the chazzan's bracha just before Shema is because it is a [hefsek](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) between the [brachah and Shema](https://www.sefaria.org/Levushei_Serad_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=bi). Based on the [Gra](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=bi&p2=Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4.5&lang2=bi) and the [Mishna Berurah](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.59.4?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.59.24&lang2=bi), it is not clear if it is a hefsek birchas hamitzvah or birchas hanehenin. If, however, we labor under the assumption that the brachah is a birchas hamitzvah on the Shema itself, then it seems there should be no issue of hefsek when davening outside the zman since the mitzva of the Shema itself isn't even being fulfilled.

I received a psak to *not* say amen to the chazzan's bracha just before Shema even outside the zman for Shema; apparently not everyone agrees with the logic above. I didn't get a reason so I decided to toss the "why" over to this community:

Why not say Amen after birchas ahavah when davening outside the zman for Shema?

The mitzvah is not in effect at that time; and, compounding the problem, when discussing the Shema of Shacharis, the mitzvah of Shema has already been fulfilled (assuming that the davener said Shema during the zman).

Comment: "Why not say Amen after birchas ahavah when davening outside the zman for Shema?" Indeed some do. You can ask about the psak you received but know it isn't the only psak out there.

Comment: Maybe as you say they were worried for hefsek birchas hanehenin? Why do you assume the psak you received labors under the assumption that the brachah is a birchas hamitzvah? What you're seeking (a reason to not say amen after zman accd to the birkat hamitzva side) may not exist

Comment: Lo plug? (15 char)

Comment: My practice which I learned from a rabbi of mine is the opposite of yours. I _do_ say amen for the chazan's bracha when it's outside the zman.